# How to check File Size or dimension?

Tags: c#

```
 var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "(*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.JPG;*.GIF";
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlg.FileName)) return;
        var fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
```

I am using this code but not find how to find size or dimension of image?

Comment: i want to get image but with specific size or dimension

Comment: Get a drawing.image from the file name and .height/.width

Comment: hint: fs.Length represents the length of the stream in bytes

Comment: Is it possible to get size like 50kb etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use FileInfo given path of this file and use Length as

```
var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "(*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.JPG;*.GIF";
dlg.ShowDialog();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlg.FileName)) 
  return;

FileInfo info = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);
Console.Write("Length In Bytes:"+info.Length);
```

Answer (score 6):

Answered as a part of this question: [Limit image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491597/limit-image-size/12491758#12491758)

```
string filename = // get it from OpenFileDialog
var length = new FileInfo(filename).Length;
Image img = Image.FromFile(filename);
var w = img.Width;
var h = img.Height;
```

Comment: var length = new FileInfo(filename).Length; this length is size of image in KB?

Comment: this is the lenght of the image file (as you can see by reading `FileInfo.Length` documentation) in bytes. Therefore it is size of the image.